# Django custom model class functions- .save()

Tags: django, view, models

Can you define a function in a Django model that will use the .save() function.

```
Class Restaurant(models.Model)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    rating = models.PositiveIntegerField(validators=[MaxValueValidator(100), MinValueValidator(0)], default=50)

    def change_rating(self, value)
        self.rating += value
        self.rating.save()
```

Will this work? Is this best practices?

Is it better to accomplish this in views like so:

```
*views.py

def change_rating(name, amount):
  res = Restaurant.objects.get(name=name)
  res.rating += amount
  res.save()
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Did you try? What reason do you have to think this would not be good practice?

Comment: My programming skills are at the "I can make it work" level. I was curious if there is something I am not aware of that would make another way of accomplishing this a better option. Really, I am just looking for opinions and thoughts.

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest model managers for this kind of cases

**model_managers.py**

```
from django.db import models

class CustomManager(models.Manager):

    def change_rating(self, value, **kwargs):
        x = self.get(**kwargs)
        x.rating += value
        x.save()
```

**models.py**

```
from . model_managers import CustomManager

class Restaurant(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    rating = models.PositiveIntegerField(validators=[MaxValueValidator(100), MinValueValidator(0)], default=50)
    objects = CustomManager()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

**execution command**

```
Restaurant.objects.change_rating(25, name=name)
```

Comment: This seems like a pointless use of managers, which are for *class*-level operations.